Filter out components that return null
I have this scenario:
const Comp = () => {
   const record = useRecordContext()  // local context
   const {read} = usePermissions(record.type)   // global context
   const somethingElse = useSomethingElse()  

   if (!read || record.status !== 'OPEN' || somethingElse) {
       return null
   }

   return ...
}

A component that might return null or ReactElement. The return logic is same everywhere, this is why it is inside the component and used like this across the app.
The thing is that whatever Comp returns, when used like <Comp /> it is always a valid element. It is included to the Virtual DOM. There is no way we can know what it returns without mounting it.
When I have array of components like this [<Comp />, <Comp2 /> ...] sometimes I need to filter out those that will return null. Let's say I need the length of the elements that will render something on the Real DOM, not only on Virtual DOM.
Since only the Virtual DOM knows what a component returns, it is not possible to tell without rendering it what it might return.
I can move the logic outside of component into a hook, but it might not always work as intended, since I use local context providers as well. Also I want that logic to be stick with the component, if I separate it I might forget using it. If I create utility function for that, I have to manually put all the things it needs, since it won't be able to get them itself using context providers (utility functions can't use hooks)
I am looking for design patterns or tricks to keep the logic together with the component, so I can use it without thinking for its logic and in the same time I want to be able to filter it out as an empty component
Not looking for a trick similar to passing things from child to parent that tells him what it rendered.

if you need data to render the container, that certainly means that these date have to be stored in the container and not in the child.

Then how i will reuse that rendering logic? If I separate it from the component, that means I have to use 2 things to make 1. I can't ensure that they will be always used together. I want them to stick together

I don't found a example where the logic is need in the container and the child in the same time. edit your question to add more details.

@mmm I didn't mention anything about container in my question. What I want is a way to keep that logic together with the component, in order to reuse that logic, without thinking for it on every usage, and in the same time it should not be directly inside the component, because then there is no way to detect if component returns null. I can't find a solution for those 2 problems together

what I call "container" is the parent component of Comp.
